# Can we disable the "Start reviewing now" button on the stats tab when one does not meet the criteria to do reviews?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, design

I recently joined a new site, and had a look at the review page. I currently don't have enough reputation to be able to do any reviews, which is clearly indicated on the review page.

[image]

If I then visit the stats tab ( [site].stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats ) I see the following:

[image]

When I click that button it leads to <strike>disappointment</strike> [site].stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits which shows me a banner similar to the first screenshot.

**Can we either remove or grey this button out for those that don't meet the criteria to do the reviews?**

If we choose to do the latter, can we just put in a tooltip on hover with the same text that is in the banner, to make clear why the button is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is taken care of. If you are on the review stats page for a queue where you cant review, you will not be shown the link to review.

---

> check out those cool stats!
> link to review no longer taunts
> for low rep user